# Google map padding bottom doesn't work on flutter Android

Tags: android, google-maps, flutter

```
gmap.GoogleMap myMap = gmap.GoogleMap(
  mapType: gmap.MapType.normal,
  myLocationEnabled: true,
  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 100, right:10),// works
  padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 200, right:10),//no work!!
  initialCameraPosition: _kGooglePlex,
  onMapCreated: (gmap.GoogleMapController controller) {
    _controller.complete(controller);
  }
);
```

I want to show the current location button right-bottom.

I use padding to move the currentlocation buttom, but

`EdgeInsets.only(top)` works but `EdgeInsets.only(bottom)` doesn't work

Why does it happen?? or is there any work-around way to set button right-bottom??

Answer (score 0):

You need to don't to have two separate padding properties as this will cause errors, you can just define both `top` and `bottom` padding in one property. For example:

```
padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 100, right: 10, bottom: 200),
```